# Cannot read property 'configName' of Undefined

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular2-template

I am getting `Cannot read property 'configName' of undefined`. I tried implementing the already answered questions but couldn't fix this.
Relevant portions of my code:

**html**

```
<select  class="form-control" name="configName" [(ngModel)]="configSearch.configName">
                <option selected>Select Config Name</option>
                <option value="Card Transaction Config">Card Transaction Config</option>
                <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
                <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
            </select>
```

**component.ts**

```
    public configSearch: ConfigSearch;
    ngOnit() {
    this.configSearch = {
        'configName': '',
        'startTime': '',
        'endTime': ''
    };
}
```

**config-search-mapping**

```
    export interface ConfigSearch {
    configName: string;
    startTime: string;
    endTime: string;
}
```

Comment: I think you can try configSearch?.configName

Comment: @PareshGami Tried. Doesn't work.

Comment: it's better to initialize like this : `this.configSearch = {
        configName: '',
        startTime: '',
        endTime: ''
    };` based on your interface .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without doing it on ngOnit(), you can directly initialize as,

```
public configSearch: ConfigSearch = {
        'configName': '',
        'startTime': '',
        'endTime': ''
    };
```

Comment: it works because ngOnit is  called after the template loaded